# Loading image into ImageVew from Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm developing an Android app where I'm trying to download an image from Google Drive using Drive API by using the following code for it but I am stuck here itself.
How to load this image into ImageView.

```
String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId)
  .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Comment: What is your actual issue with the following piece of code? Can't you manage to download the file using Drive API? Also, check [the documentation for making media downloads in Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-download#implementation_details) and let me know if using ```MediaHttpDownloader``` and ```MediaHttpDownloaderProgressListener``` helped to solve the issue :D

Comment: My question is how to I load retrieved data in the ImageView after this line 'driveService.files().get(fileId)
  .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);'